# How do I Log on as Administrator using Remote Desktop?

Tags: windows-7, desktop, login, remote, administrator

As title says.. How do I logon as Administrator using remote desktop..

I have a laptop and 3 Dekstop PC's all running windows 7 etc.. I can create accounts on my Desktops and connect to them via remote desktop.. But I cannot connect as the administrator..

The problem I have is that all my work, folders and programs are on the Administrator account as Im the only user. If I can only connect by setting up a new user I cant use any of my files, folders and programs..

When I say "connect to desktop" it asks for username & password.. My Administrator account doesnt have a password..  Although I have tried setting one on the desktop and using "Administrator" as the username and then my newly set password.. But I cannot log in.

Im confused!

What am I missing ?

Comment: From a security perspective this is easy - stop logging in as Administrator.  Its just plain risky.  Microsoft intentionally makes this hard. Move your data to a regular user account and use it. (Sorry to be preachy)

Comment: Change you settings on your RDP client to this:
https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/kb/941641

Answer (score 3, accepted):

By default accounts without passwords are restricted from logging in via remote desktop (they are limited to console logins only).  You can override this by following the steps below:

> To configure the Remote Desktop host computer to accept user name with
>   blank password, go to Control Panel -> Administrative Tools (Under
>   System and Maintenance in Windows Vista) -> Local Security Policy.
>   Alternatively, run GPEdit.msc (Group Policy Editor).
>
> Then, expand Security Policies -> Local Securities -> Security Options
>   (for user using Group Policy Editor or GPEdit.msc, expand Local
>   Computer Policy -> Computer Configuration -> Windows Settings ->
>   Security Settings -> Local Policies -> Security Options). Locate
>   Accounts: Limit local account use of blank passwords to console logon
>   only policy, and set its value to Disabled.

Comment: @Martin, Since it's a quote, where's the link to the source?

Answer (score 1):

Best practices aside for a moment (don't log in as admin) I would need some information. I assume these are all local accounts? If not, check the domain you are logging into. If it says logging onto [computer name] and you really want to use a domain admin account use: domain\user for the login id.

Also, what is the error message it gives you? (I would have just posted this in comments, but I can't yet).